# Solve $y' + y^2 = \frac{1}{x^2}$ by introducing $z = xy$ as a new function.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

**Question:**

Solve the equation:

$$y' + y^2 = \frac{1}{x^2},~~~~~~~~~x > 0$$

by introducing $z = xy$

**Attempted answer:**

$z = xy \Rightarrow y = \frac{z}{x}$

Taking the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$ using he product rule:

$$y' = \frac{z'}{x} - \frac{z}{x}$$

Adding this into the original equation:

$$\frac{z'}{x} - \frac{z}{x^2} + \frac{z^2}{x^2} = \frac{1}{x^2}$$

Putting $z$ and $x$ on each side:

$$\frac{z'}{1-z^2 + z} = \frac{1}{x}$$

Integrating on each side:

$$\int \frac{1}{1-z^2 + z}dz = \int \frac{1}{x} dx$$

This produces

$$z(x) = \frac{(1+\sqrt{5})c_1x^{\sqrt{5}}+1-\sqrt{5}}{(2c_1 x^{\sqrt{5}}+2)}$$

Substituting back to $y$:

$$y(x) = \frac{(1+\sqrt{5})c_1x^{\sqrt{5}}+1-\sqrt{5}}{x(2c_1 x^{\sqrt{5}}+2)}$$

This seems all and well, but the expected answer contains yet another solution:

$$y = \frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2x}$$

How does this second solution arise? Since there is an $x^2$ in the question, I think that a solution might have been dropped at some point.

Comment: One of these is for $c_1=0$. The other is for "$c_1=\infty$".

Comment: Let C1=0 to get the other solution

Comment: @AbhishekVangipuram How does this produce the plus and minus sign in $1\pm\sqrt{5}$?

Comment: There is a square missing after the first application of the product rule. It's ok later on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the division that must be different from zero as GSofer pointed in his good answer but you can also deduce that solution by other methods:
$$y' + y^2 = \frac{1}{x^2}$$
By inspection $y_p=\frac  A x$
$$-\frac A {x^2}+\frac {A^2}{x^2}=\frac 1 {x^2}$$
$$ \implies A^2-A-1=0$$
$$\implies A=\frac 12 \pm\frac {\sqrt 5}{2} \implies y =\frac {1\pm \sqrt 5}{2x}$$

Answer (score 3):

When you divide by $1-z^2+z$, you're actually excluding the possibility of this term to be $0$. But note that if it is $0$, you get the desired solution.